# isql not connecting to the database

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc, unixodbc

I have installed unixodbc and mssql drivers on the centos machine , but i am not able to connecto to the remote database using isql database username password.

odbcinst -j

```
unixODBC 2.3.1
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

cat /etc/odbcinst.ini (this file is blank)

I created an entry in /etc/odbc.ini

```
[empower]
Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Description=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
DSN=dsnname
Trace=No
Server=servername
Port=1433
Database=db_env
ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly


isql dsnname username password gives the below error :
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Need to know if i am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The file "/etc/odbcinst.ini" should not be empty. It should contain an entry similar to this one:

```
[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.0
UsageCount=1
```

(I have verified that the above entry is automatically added by the "RedHat Enterprise Server 7" instructions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server). Tested on a clean install of CentOS_7.)

Then your "/etc/odbc.ini" can define the DSN named "empower" as

```
[empower]
Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Trace=No
Server=servername
Database=db_env
ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly
```

and `isql` should be able to connect with

```
isql empower MyID MyPWD
```

Comment: I found /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.1.0 and updated /etc/odbcinst.ini as per your instructions. But i am still getting the same error. I can login to the sql server Db with the sql studio using my windows credential. Not sure if i am missing anything, i guess its not a credentials problem as the error doesnt complain about it.

Comment: You may have used an outdated set of instructions for installing msodbcsql. Try again, using the "RedHat Enterprise Server 7" instructions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server). I just did that on a clean install of CentOS_7 and both `isql` and Python/pyodbc worked fine for me.